# Como se llaman estas líneas para relacionar comentarios indentados en CSS

Tags: html5, css3, material-design, responsive

Quiero crear un diseño similar a este:
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es como se pueden crear estas lineas mediante css, y como se conserva un diseño responsivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo con seudoselectores

el seudoselector `:before` con `position:relative` y definiendo `border-left` y `border-bottom` te permitiría dibujar las líneas.

el comentario principal debiera tener `position:relative` y un `z-index` positivo para quedar por encima de las líneas del primer comentario anidado.

Igual tendrías que jugar con el padding de los seudoselectores y no es tan trivial. Posiblemente haya otras maneras más elegantes.

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.comment {
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #0e9b8e;
    width: 99%;
    max-width: 99%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1%;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-indent: 0;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 10px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px rgba(200,200,200,0.6);
}

.primary {
  background:white;
  z-index:2;
}

.secondary {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.secondary p {
margin-top: 0px;
}

.secondary:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: relative;
  padding: 100px 10px 50px;
  left: -32px;
  top: -30px;
  border-left: 1px solid #0e9b8e;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0e9b8e;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="comment primary"><p>Hola soy el comentario principal.</p>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</div>
  
  <div class="comment secondary"><p>Hola soy un comentario anidado.</p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </div>
  
  <div class="comment secondary"><p>Hola soy el segundo anidado.</p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</div>
  
  <div class="comment secondary"><p>Hola soy el tercer comentario anidado.</p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
</div>
```